# Android Java throws unusual error when passing int value to the setText() method of TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm trying to create a Android project. I have this XML layout code:

```xml
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/music_duration_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_of_progress_and_duration_text"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/music_place_slider"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/music_place_slider"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/music_place_slider"/>
```

I access it in my fragment like this:

```java
TextView musicDurationTextView;
musicDurationTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.music_duration_text_view);
```

However, when I try to change its text like this,

```java
musicDurationTextView.setText(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
```

it throws an error:

```
2023-07-20 10:37:06.120  9023-9023  AndroidRuntime          net...ftware.great_site.keeptrackv1  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: net.formalsoftware.great_site.keeptrackv1, PID: 9023
                                                                                                    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3ed40
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:455)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:7295)
                                                                                                        at net.formalsoftware.great_site.keeptrackv1.NowPlayingFragment.playPauseAudio(NowPlayingFragment.java:118)
                                                                                                        at net.formalsoftware.great_site.keeptrackv1.NowPlayingFragment.lambda$onViewCreated$0$net-formalsoftware-great_site-keeptrackv1-NowPlayingFragment(NowPlayingFragment.java:52)
                                                                                                        at net.formalsoftware.great_site.keeptrackv1.NowPlayingFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7659)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7636)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30156)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8176)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

If I change it to this,

```java
musicDurationTextView.setText("mediaPlayer.getDuration()");
```

it works fine.

Why does this throw this unusual, unrelated error when `int`s are passed to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setText` requires you to pass a String or an Android resource ID.

`mediaPlayer.getDuration()` returns an integer representing the duration, so you will have to convert it into a string so it can be passed to `setText`. You can do so by calling

Java:

```java
musicDurationTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mediaPlayer.getDuration()))
```

Kotlin:

```kotlin
musicDurationTextView.text = mediaPlayer.getDuration().toString()
```

Comment: There is no `toString()` method.

Comment: Sorry that was in Kotlin, in Java you can use `String.valueOf(mediaPlayer.getDuration());`

Answer (score 1):

All resources are distinguished by their id and IDs are int values. So when you provide an int value to `setText` function, it will try to find the resource whose id is provided by you.

To correctly set int value as a text, you need to call `toString` function or Integer.

```
musicDurationTextView.setText(Integer.toString(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
```